# boost::asio::serial_port reading after reconnecting Device

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I have a problem with the boost::asio::serial_port class reading from a GPS device (USB-Serial). Connecting the device and reading from it works fine, but when I disconnect and reconnect the device, read_some doesn't read any bytes from the port.

As boost doesn't seam to detect that the serial port is gone ( is_open() returns true ), I periodically cancel(), close() and open( GPS_PORT ) the device when I don't get data, resetting the port options on the way. But this doesn't help either, the input buffer stays empty.

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong, or is this a bug in asio? Is there a standard way to detect that the port is gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what is the exact reason in your case, but practice shows that you often need to disable `RTS` sensitivity on your serial port.

`RTS` is a pin on real `RS-232` interface that is on when a device on the other side is on.

`serial_port::read_some` invokes underlying `Windows API` function that looks on this signal.

As you don't have the real `RS-323` device, you need to rely on the driver emulation of this signal which may be faulty (and unfortunately often is).

To disable it, invoke `serial_port::set_option(DCB)` with `RTSControl` set to `RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE`.

If `close()`'ing your handle doesn't help, it may be a problem with `boost`. Source code for `close()` looks like this:

```
  boost::system::error_code close(implementation_type& impl,
      boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (is_open(impl))
    {
      if (!::CloseHandle(impl.handle_))
      {
        DWORD last_error = ::GetLastError();
        ec = boost::system::error_code(last_error,
            boost::asio::error::get_system_category());
        return ec;
      }

      impl.handle_ = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
      impl.safe_cancellation_thread_id_ = 0;
    }

    ec = boost::system::error_code();
    return ec;
  }
```

, i. e. if `CloseHandle()` fails for some reason (or hangs), the internal handle value is not beign assigned to `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and `is_open()` will always return `true`.

To work around this, check `is_open()` right after `close()`'ing, and if it returns `true`, destroy whole instance of `boost::asio::serial_port` and create it again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - but shouldn't the read also fail when the device is first opened?

Comment: Read will fail when the driver says RTS is off. When it happens depends on the driver implementation. BTW, when the read begins to succeed: ater reboot, after device reattachment, after timeout?

Comment: Ok, I just tried to set RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE - it doesn't change the behaviour. The boost::serial_port::is_open returns true, but won't start reading.
The behaviour is: connect GPS, start tool - reading, disconnect GPS, reading stops, connect again, still not reading. Restart tool: works again.

Comment: Thanks, checking for is_open() after the close() and then creating a new instance fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should get an exception of type `boost::system::system_error` when `read_some` cannot ready anymore. Try using `read` instead, maybe it returns an error and doesn't just return. You could also try the async methods; in this case the handler should get an error object when the device was disconnected.

Alterantively you could get the handle to the port using the `native()` function and call ClearCommError() on that. It might return the error.

Comment: That looks good - I'm checking the error code, but I haven't noticed the native() method yet ... with that I should be able to somehow convice the serial port to read :)

Comment: Maybe you just don't get to notice that a device was plugged out, due to the usb driver not reporting this to the OS. In that case: bad luck :/

Answer (score 1):

Despite of the easy handling of asio `boost::ip:tcp`, I think handling boost `serial_port` requires special caution on Windows 7.
I got similar problem and **got over it by resetting an instance of `boost::asio::io_service`**, `io_service_.reset()`.
I can read data asynchronously but it fails to do same thing from the second try.
In fact, it was no problem of read function itself, registering asynchronous read failed, which led immediate return from `boost::asio::io_service::run()` in second try.

I am not sure this is the same problem as original poster had because I am using newer boost library of these days.
Anyway here is my solution:

```cpp
// port open step
port_ = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::serial_port>
        (new boost::asio::serial_port(io_service_));
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_));
port_->async_read_some(....);
.......

// port close step
port_->cancel();
port_->close();
port_.reset();

io_service_.stop();
io_service_.reset();  // <-- IMPORTANT: this makes serial_port works in repeat use.
```